# javascript : create objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok. I want to create a JSON array dynamically. Case is:

Lets say, I have array:

```
var arrayCompanyUsers = ["dealers", "builders"];
```

From the above array, I want to generate another array as below:

```
[
    "dealers" : {
                  "RequestQuote" : false,
                  "PlaceOrder" : false,
                 },
    "builder" : {
                  "RequestQuote" : false,
                  "PlaceOrder" : false,
                 }
]
```

Two questions:

1. how to generate resultant array ?
2. can i access the properties as: `dealers.RequestQuote` ?

Comment: You mean, you want an Object from that array?

Comment: `[
    "dealers" : {
                  "RequestQuote" : false,
                  "PlaceOrder" : false,
                 },
    "builder" : {
                  "RequestQuote" : false,
                  "PlaceOrder" : false,
                 }
]` would not be a array.Array does not have key-value pair. You probably want to have Array of Objects like `[
    {"dealers" : {
                  "RequestQuote" : false,
                  "PlaceOrder" : false,
                 }},
    {"builder" : {
                  "RequestQuote" : false,
                  "PlaceOrder" : false,
                 }}
]`

Comment: Yes ofcourse. But my resultant array will contain objects whose names will be assigned from `arrayCompanyUsers`

Comment: All of you were right. Thanks for you all. You spent time to answer me. Collectively, I have upvoted all of you as you were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following snipped:

```
var arrayCompanyUsers = ['dealers', 'builders'];
var target = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arrayCompanyUsers.length; i++){
    var user = arrayCompanyUsers[i];
    target[user] = {
        'RequestQuote' : false,
        'PlaceOrder' : false,
    };
}
console.log(target);
```

And yes, you should be able to access the properties with `dealers.RequestQuote`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.map` to create an array of objects:

```
var output = arrayCompanyUsers.map(function(key) {
  var record = {};
  record[key] =  {
    RequestQuote : false,
    PlaceOrder : false,
  }

  record data;
})
```

To get `RequestQuote` for the "dealers" record:

```
function getValue(records, name, value) {
  var matches = records.filter(function(record) {
      return record[name] !== undefined;
    })

    if(matches.length > 0) {
      return matches[0][name][value];
    }
}

console.log(getValue(output, 'dealers', 'RequestQuote'));
// -> false
```

As an aside, your data would be easier to work with if you used the format:

```
{
  name: "dealers",
  properties: {
    RequestQuote : false,
    PlaceOrder : false,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see this : http://jsfiddle.net/zL5x6xxm/3/

```
 var arrayCompanyUsers = ["dealers", "builders"];
var result=[];
for(i=0;i<arrayCompanyUsers.length;i++)
{var x=arrayCompanyUsers[i]
    result.push('{'+ x+':{  "RequestQuote" : false, "PlaceOrder" : false, }}');  
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: When I tried your solution with some modifiction, I got `[{"x":{"RequestQuote":false,"PlaceOrder":false}},{"x":{"RequestQuote":false,"PlaceOrder":false}}]`

Comment: I did `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` to see the output

Comment: @ChintanSoni create a fiddle of it, what i wrote is according to the requirement you asked in the question

Comment: Yes. Just a little correction with your answer. I wanted `"dealers"` , `"builders"` instead of `"x"`